# Filtering Rails 5 model using multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application that has hundreds of products.  I created a simple filter search bar and it works great for a single parameter, but I would like to add multiple parameters and return any product that contains one of the search parameters.

Here is my working code for a single parameter; I would show what I've tried to add multiple params, but I am a bit out of my depth.

**products_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @products = Product.all.order('LOWER(name)')
    if params[:q]
      @products = Product.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%").all.order('LOWER(name)')
    end
end
```

**_searchbar.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: 'search-form', :html => {class: 'form'}) do %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: 'Product Name', class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to add checkboxes like a 'top sellers', 'womens', 'size'?

Comment: Do you mean a search more like "name ILIKE `p[:q]` OR name ILIKE `p[r]`" or "name ILIKE `p[:q]` OR description ILIKE `p[:q]`" ?

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran Yes, that would be ideal @taryn-east I am not sure, but to be more specific, if someone searches red and blue, all products with the `name` red or blue would be in the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following:

```
# :query need to be an array
# Eg:
# "Product name 1, Product name 2, Product name 3" =>  params[:q].split(', ')
# => ["Product name 1", "Product name 3", "Product name 3"]

search_string = []
query.each { |q| search_string << "name ILIKE ?" }
search_string = search_string.join(' OR ')

Product.where(search_string, *query)
```

Answer (score 0):

We should know the operation behind. The sql query must be like this:

```
select * from products where name ilike '%name1%' or name ilike '%name2%';
```

According you code:

```
select * from products where name ilike '%name1,name2%'
```

That's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using following steps like if you need to use input field then form look like this

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: 'search-form', :html => {class: 'form'}) do %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :x, params[:x], placeholder: 'Product Name1', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :y, params[:y], placeholder: 'Product Name2', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :z, params[:z], placeholder: 'Product Name3', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Or you need this filtering key is in the checkbox then form look like this

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: 'search-form', :html => {class: 'form'}) do %>
    <%= check_box_tag("x[]", "x") %> Xname
    <%= check_box_tag("y[]", "y") %> Yname
    <%= check_box_tag("z[]", "z") %> Zname
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Now update the controller look like this

```
if params[:x] || params[:y] || params[:z]
    @products = Product.where('true')
    @products = @products.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:x]}%") unless params[:x].blank?
    @products = @products.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:y]}%") unless params[:y].blank?
    @products = @products.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:z]}%") unless params[:z].blank?
    @products = @products.order('LOWER(name)')
else
    @products = Product.all.order('LOWER(name)')
end
```

Hope it helps